# How did Culler define the relationship between literary studies and cultural studies after ‘Literary Theory: A Very Short Introduction’?

Tags: theory, jonathan-culler, literary-theory-short-introduction

Yesterday, [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/) asked [Is Jonathan Culler saying that literary theory is effectively the same subject as cultural studies?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16797/2191) The question was based on the second edition of Culler's *Literary Theory: A Very Short Introduction*. My [answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/16835/2191) was based on the book's first edition and [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289/) commented, "What do you make of the fact that Culler pulled this distinction out from the 2e? It seems he changed his mind?"

*Literary Theory: A Very Short Introduction* was not Culler's last book on literary theory, so I wonder if those other works shed some light on how Culler conceived the relationship between literary and cultural studies in other books after 1997, the year of the first edition of *Literary Theory: A Very Short Introduction*. Do other publications by Culler after 1997 reflect a change of mind about the relationship between literary and cultural studies?